# Highcharts: Duplicate X-Axis Labels when dataGrouping is enabled (by Month)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm experiencing an issue when grouping data by month. I believe it to be a bug with the size of the dataset (January 1, 2018 - April 30, 2018) that I'm using but perhaps there is a better way of utilizing `dataGrouping`. The issue that I'm experiencing is that the X-Axis labels are not correct.

For a date range of January 1, 2018 to April 30, 2018:

**Expected X-Axis to Be:**
"Jan, '18" "Feb, '18" "Mar, '18" "Apr, '18"

**Actual X-Axis:**
"Jan, '18" "Feb, '18" "Mar, '18" "Mar, '18" "Apr, '18"

In my example ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/engemasa/w69ptqs0/)), I'm conditionally enabling dataGrouping on line 76: `data.dataGrouping.enabled = (e.target.value === 'month');`

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? are you saying that your bar looks so small when you do grouping? Is it because of the responsiveness of the chart?

Comment: March appears twice in the chart, I think that is the issue.

Comment: That is correct: March is appearing twice for this date range. The data is just a small sample of the application working on. I can replicate this with various datasets.

Comment: For the second March `this.value` returns 1522500000000 which is to say `Saturday, March 31, 2018 12:40:00 PM`. This probably has something to do with how the approximation works, not that I can say for sure. Ref: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.dataGrouping. It looks like it groups 30 days as a month, no matter the real length.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution: Use HighStocks and not HighCharts

I have an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/engemasa/w69ptqs0/5/) with the result. Summary:

Use HighScocks and just turn off some features to make it appear like a Highstock chart:

```
var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('myChart', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        width: null
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
                if (grouping === 'date') {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e, \'%y', this.value);
                } else {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b, \'%y', this.value);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    navigator: {
        enabled: false
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            color: 'white'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: '#0E7BBA',
        style: {
            color: 'white'
        },
        formatter: function() {
            var s = ''
            if (grouping === 'date') {
                s = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + '</b>';
            } else {
                s = '<b>' + 'Date: ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + '<br />' +
                '<b>Month: ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %Y', this.x) + '</b>';
            }
            s += '<br />' + this.points[0].series.name + ': ' + this.y;
            return s;
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
        series: []
    }
);
```